# Cloning Windows SBS 2003 to different machines (with different hardware configurations)

Tags: windows-server-2003, disk-image, cloning

I'd like to save time and clone an existing Win 2k3 server to new hardware.

Is this possible / advisable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its perfectly possible, if you use some good cloning software that will deal with the hardware issues. The primary problem is have a different disk controller, this will often cause windows to blue screen on boot. A number of cloning tools such as Acronis will deal with this issue for you (most of the time).